# I want to print a pattern by some different

Tags: java

I want to print a pattern only by using two loops by taking the input from user, what i want to know is that whatever logic i am using from that way is it possible to print pattern dynamically according to the user input......
            pattern i want is

```
   1   
  121  
 12321 
1234321




            import java.util.Scanner;

            class PatternOneTwoOne
            {
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                /*  Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Enter the no of rows");
                    int no=s.nextInt();*/
                    for(int i=1;i<=4;i++)
                    {
                        int k=1;
                        for(int j=1;j<=7;j++)
                        {
                            if(j>=5-i && j<=3+i)
                            {
                                System.out.print(k);
                                int r=j<4?k++:k--;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.out.print(" ");
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: OK can you clue us in on what the exact problem is with _your_ code?  Most people reading this can bang out a script to solve this, but that's not what Stack Overflow is all about.

Comment: Here is a hint: Write code which correctly prints, say, the second line.  You'll have spaces, numbers, and then more spaces.  Then, find a way to generalize that for all lines in the pyramid.

Comment: *i want to print the above mentioned pattern according to the input given by user*. Then do it. Create a variable baseLength, containing the length of the base of the pyramid (i.e. 7 in your example), and rewrite your code to use baseLength instead of hardcoded numbers. Then test it with various other values of baseLength, then ask the user the value of baseLength before actually printing the pyramid.

Comment: Your first other hard-coded number is 4, the height of the pyramid. What's thee relation between 7 and 4? What if the base length was 9? What would the height become? what for 11? what for 13? What for 3? You should be able to find this out.

Comment: it would be better to give ur code by whatever u r suggesting..it would be easy to understand for me otherwise i tried diffrent changes in prgrm which is not working at all JBNizet

Comment: I won't do your homework. It's up to you to think. Not just copy paste some stranger's solution on the internet. If you don't like thinking about problems, then programming is not for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework dump without any research effort.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use this it will help you surely **USING TWO FOR LOOPS**

```
import java.util.*;
 public class PatternOneTwoOne
   {
    public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of lines[height of triangle] : \t");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int k=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        k=1;
        for(int j=0; j<(n+i); j++)
        {
           if(j<n-i-1)
                System.out.print(" ");
            else
            {
                System.out.print(""+k);
                if(j<(n-1))
                    k++;

                else
                    k--;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}

}
```

Output: - [Output of Above Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95puu.png)

Comment: i want to solve it only using two loops

Comment: then you must be mentioned in your question